# This "really simple" simplexml scrip't isn't working

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> 
<pages>
<page>
    <title>Home</title>
    <content>Lorem Ipsum</content>
</page>
<page>
    <title>Pictures</title>
    <content>Lorem Ipsum</content>
</page>
<page>
    <title>Information</title>
    <content>Lorem Ipsum</content>
</page>
</pages>
```

My XML

```
$url = "xml->build.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

$i = 1;

foreach($xml->page as $page) {
    echo "<strong>Page ".$i.":</strong> ".$page->title."<br/>";
    $i++;
}
```

My PHP

I'm getting:

Warning: simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "xml->build.xml"

Just from that simple script! Any Ideas? :)

Updated, this is the exact XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> 
<pages>
<page>
    <title>Home</title>
    <content>Lorem Ipsum</content>
</page>
<page>
    <title>Pictures</title>
    <content>Lorem Ipsum</content>
</page>
<page>
    <title>Information</title>
    <content>Lorem Ipsum</content>
</page>
</pages>
<css>
<css-tag>
    <title>background-color</title>
    <value>#FFF</value>
</css-tag>
</css>
<layout>1</layout>
```

Comment: You actually have a file on the disk named "xml->build.xml"? If not, where are you taking the XML from?

Comment: That's what it says to do [here](http://webhole.net/2009/07/26/how-to-parse-xml-with-php-part-3-last-fetching-the-results/) I've tried "$url = "build.xml";" But I get even more errors

Comment: Well, *where* is your XML file?

Comment: In the same folder as my script :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's happening because you're trying to read a file that is not there. If your file is named `build.xml` and is stored in the same directory as the PHP script, replace:

```
$url = "xml->build.xml";
```

with:

```
$url = dirname(__FILE__) . "/build.xml";
```

Comment: Warning: simplexml_load_file(): /customers/MYSITENAME/MYSITENAME/httpd.www/userthemes/buildtest/build/build.xml:17: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document in /customers/MYSITENAME/MYSITENAME/httpd.www/userthemes/buildtest/build/getpages.php on line 11 Warning: simplexml_load_file(): in /customers/MYSITENAME/MYSITENAME/httpd.www/userthemes/buildtest/build/getpages.php on line 11 Warning: simplexml_load_file(): ^ in /customers/MYSITENAME/MYSITENAME/httpd.www/userthemes/buildtest/build/getpages.php on line 11

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /customers/MYSITENAME/MYSITENAME/httpd.www/userthemes/buildtest/build/getpages.php on line 15

Comment: @RichardMuthwill, this time the XML is loaded correctly then, but the XML is invalid. Try copy / pasting the exact XML code you posted in the question in that XML file.

Comment: @RichardMuthwill, your posted XML file is invalid. All tags need to be inside a root tag. For example, add a `<root>` tag right under the `<?xml` declaration, and a `</root>` tag at the very end of the file. Then, `foreach()` will need to go through `$xml->pages->page` instead of just `$xml->page`.

Comment: There we go, looks like it's working! Thank you so much for your help Radu and everyone else! :)

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure why you get such error but this might help you resolve it

I don't think `xml->build.xml` is a valid name either can you also change it to something like `build.xml`

try

```
$url = "build.xml";
if(!is_file($url))
    die("File Does not exist");

if(!is_readable($url))
    die("File is not readeable");


$xml = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents($url));
var_dump($xml);

$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
var_dump($xml);
```

If `simplexml_load_string` works definitely `simplexml_load_file` would work too

Update

Your XML is wrong the format should be like this

```
$url = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> 
<doc>
<pages>
<page>
    <title>Home</title>
    <content>Lorem Ipsum</content>
</page>
<page>
    <title>Pictures</title>
    <content>Lorem Ipsum</content>
</page>
<page>
    <title>Information</title>
    <content>Lorem Ipsum</content>
</page>
</pages>
<css>
<css-tag>
    <title>background-color</title>
    <value>#FFF</value>
</css-tag>
</css><layout>1</layout>
</doc>';
```

Comment: Omg this is just getting worse xD Even more errors with this script :( Maybe my web hotel doesn't run "simplexml", or is it something build into PHP?

Comment: Tell me what is the exact error you are getting now ... the you pass the first 2 stages ??? the you rename the files has i asked ???

Comment: Yup, Copied your script exactly, so instead of xml->build.xml, I just used build.xml as the URL

Comment: Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 16: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document in /customers/MYSITENAME/MYSITENAME/httpd.www/userthemes/buildtest/build/getpages.php on line 17 Warning: simplexml_load_string(): in /customers/MYSITENAME/MYSITENAME/httpd.www/userthemes/buildtest/build/getpages.php on line 17 Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^ in /customers/MYSITENAME/MYSITENAME/httpd.www/userthemes/buildtest/build/getpages.php on line 17 bool(false)

Comment: add `<doc></doc>` at the  beginning and end of the XML doc